# cutting a portion of url using regular expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following url :

http://stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com/html/estVerificationPool/estPendingBugs.php?team_name=General%20administration

Need to  proper way to extract the value after "?" 
Need to find how to explode in perl
 just the http://example.com part out of the string, and store it in its own variable, split it and save in a variable before passing it.

Comment: pls could nay one answer this??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't do it yourself, use the [URI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI) module, which is designed to make sense of this kind of data.

```
my $uri = URI->new('http://hostname.com/...?...');
$uri->query;  # The value after the '?'
$uri->scheme; # "http"
$uri->host;   # hostname.com
```

Comment: install URI with CPAN (yes, you can use modules).  Use URI in your code with *use URI;* to parse your URI string (like the code above), additionally you can *use URI::QueryParam;* and get the $u->query_param function which can retrieve all of the paramters used in the query, or just the one you're interested in, *$u->query_param('team_name')* returns *General Admission*

Answer (score 3):

An expansion of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16662576/46235) answer, includes [query_param](https://metacpan.org/module/URI::QueryParam#first_value-u-query_param-key):

```
use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;
my $url = 'http://stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com/html/estVerificationPool/estPendingBugs.php?team_name=General%20administration';
my $uri = URI->new( $url );
my @keys = $uri->query_param(); 
# @keys contains the query parameter names
my $team_name = $uri->query_param( 'team_name' ); 
# $team_name contains the value of the team_name parameter
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this just a simple split that's required? If so...

```
my $foo = "http://stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com/html/estVerificationPool/estPendingBugs.php?team_name=General%20administration";
my @values = split( '\?', $foo );
print $values[1];
```

There are better ways that are more URL aware, but if that does the trick...

Answer (score 1):

This regex:

```
^http://([^/]*)/[^?]*\?(.*)$
```

when applied to this string:

```
http://stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com/html/estVerificationPool/estPendingBugs.php?team_name=General%20administration
```

will yield these captured patterns

```
1. stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com
2. team_name=General%20administration
```

The complete code for Perl would be:

```
$url = "http://stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com/html/estVerificationPool/estPendingBugs.php?team_name=General%20administration";
($domain, $query) = ($url =~ m{^http://([^/]*)/[^?]*\?(.*)$});
```

With `$domain` and `$query` being the parts you want, although using a built in library like Pilcrow suggested is probably wiser.

Comment: i want to split the string from ?

Comment: ie, need to split team_name=General%20administration only

Comment: So you want all of the actual field names split out, so you can create a dictionary of values like { team_name="General%20administration", another_key="another_value", etc... }?

Comment: need to split as two strings
1. http://stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com/html/estVerificationPool/estPendingBugs.php
2. ?team_name=General%20administration

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more applicable code that should help, but Pilcrows suggestion is probably wiser.

Comment: I got the result :

1st= stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com   
2nd =  team_name=General%20administration

i want to cut only from ?
i need all other portion

Comment: I tried with belo code

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $url="http://stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com/html/estVerificationPool/estPendingBugs.php?team_name=General%20administration";
$url =~  s/(?<=php).*//g;
print $url;

i got the desired result

Answer (score 1):

To extract the value after `?`, use

```
$url="http://stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com/html/estVerificationPool/estPendingBugs.php?team_name=General%20administration";
($query) = $url =~ /.+?\?(.+)/;
```

To get the domain name from url and save in the save variable

```
($url) = $url =~ m{(http://.+?)/};
```

hope this will help

Comment: i have used the code like below :

     #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string;
my $url="http://stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com/html/estVerificationPool/estPendingBugs.php?team_name=General%20administration";
#$url =~  s/(?<=team_name=).*//g;
($string)=$url=~/.+?\?(.+)/;
($url)=$url=~/(http://.+?)//;
print $url;
and got the error like below :
perl test.pl
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/( <-- HERE http:/ at test.pl line 8.

Comment: you should escape the '/' from matching string as its delimiter used for matching, use<br> ($url)=$url=~/(http:\/\/.+?)\//;